# Can a paper be presented by two presenters in a conference

Tags: conference, presentation

I am a beginner in research papers and doesn't know much about registration and presenting.

Can two authors register for the same conference and present the paper (together)?

Answer (score 10):

Registration and presentation of a paper are two somewhat separate issues. Normally, presenters at a conference must register, but there is no rule that says only one author of a paper can register for a given conference.

In general, however, papers normally have only one presenter, as the logistics of a conference normally work against having multiple speakers for a single presentation. (The presentation time is not that long, transferring a microphone between speakers, ensuring proper "flow" of the talk across the change in presenters, and so on, all tend to work against the idea of multiple presenters for a given paper.)

Comment: so does this mean that the person who registers is the only one who can present the paper.

Comment: Normally, you can't present the paper without being registered for the conference. However, any registered author of the paper can normally present the paper. (As I said, more than one author of a paper can register for the same conference!)

Comment: I have presented with a colleague at a conference, although I do agree that it is rare. In our case, we both worked on significantly different aspects of the paper, and it made sense for each of us to describe our contributions individually.

Answer (score 8):

As @aeismail said, registration and presentation are two separate things. I don't have a *vast* conference experience, but from what I've observed/done until now:

**Registration**

Registration is more about attending the conference.

Most conferences require at least *one author* of a paper to *register for a "full" fee/participation*.

To explain, I've seen reduced fees for students or options to win a free/reduced stay sponsored by the conference (this usually requires a motivation letter or things like that). So, the conference usually requires one registration at full price, and then other authors can register and attend at a reduced fee if they're eligible. Reduced fees (about 10-20%) for members of various organizations (e.g. IEEE members) still count as full fees.

**Presentations**

It's very uncommon to see two people presenting. And it's substantially harder for them -- for the reasons @aeismail said; it's hard to get the dynamic right and you will potentially loose a lot of time on the switches.

However, *it can be done*: I did it. Just as in @ChrisGregg comment, I had a truly collaborative paper with a colleague: we joined our substantially different work in a single application, and knew only the basics about the other ones contribution, so we decided to present our own contributions each.

It required more work and preparation than any other oral presentation (conference or otherwise) I ever did. We had to really know what we were doing, we both needed to know each others slides and their contents well. We had to practice being *really good at presenting our own parts*, and then *practice presenting together*, especially the switches. The switches had to be fast and natural. We actually switched two times I think (person A - person B - person A) (or even three times, not sure?). But *every presenter's part had to be a whole "chapter" all in it self.* There's much less room for improvisation (even the tiny ones within one slide can confuse the other person). The flow of the presentation is also more constricted -- what is the most natural way to present a work might require way to many switches. So, you have to ensure a minimal number of switches while still keeping the presentation flow natural and concise. And, I did feel kind of out-of-place just hovering around waiting for the switch while my colleague was presenting.

Comment: I've seen a few two-person presentations, and am convinced that in such cases, two heads are _not_ better than one.  I have yet to see a single instance where splitting a talk between two people enhanced _any_ aspect of a talk.

Comment: @debray I actually haven't seen any of them (except mine). I'm not sure how good my double-presentation was, but I know we had to put _a lot_ of effort in to it to get it to a level we were comfortable with before presenting before the audience. I'm just saying, it can be done.

Comment: I recently did it and slightly regretted it. I prepared the slides and the presentation and a co-author asked me an hour before the talk if he could present the first part (he had been practising the night before) since he wanted some face-time. He did a good job but the split involved me starting on the most technical slide of the talk, which was really difficult for a "cold start". Eventually I warmed up but I really left that first slide behind me. (It went fine and was probably good from the author perspective, but not from the audience's. With practice it would have been easier.)

Answer (score 5):

I and Misha Sodin did exactly that on the last IMC meeting (though it wasn't a single paper but a survey of a series of related papers) and nobody had any problem with that. We just felt that 50 minutes is a bit too little to tell everything we wanted in an understandable way and split the presentation into two parts. Of course, nobody wants to listen to the same talk twice, but if your paper can be split into two more or less independent parts (making some cross-references is OK as long as you avoid vicious circles and state clearly what you refer to), then I see no problem whatsoever with you presenting one part and your co-author another one. Just make sure that people who go to only one of these talks still have a chance to understand something.

Answer (score 2):

I've occasionally seen a situation where, in a conference session divided into short talks (say 20 minutes), two co-authors will speak back-to-back on the same paper (though each focuses on different aspects).  This obviously needs the consent and cooperation of the organizers to get consecutive time slots.  The talks normally have titles like:

- Integrability in quantum category theory I: Applications to the derivation of isometries
- Integrability in quantum category theory II: Connections to an example of Banach

to make it clear that they are closely related.

Comment: I've seen the same thing, except with the talks not necessarily being back-to-back, or even in the logical order.  I assume this was because the speakers didn't get their acts together to discuss their plans with the organizers far enough ahead of time.

Comment: At some meetings, it's hard to coordinate, particularly if you can't specify which session you'd like to contribute to (as is the case for APS meetings).

Comment: I've been one of the speakers in the "not necessarily ... logical order" situation that @MarkMeckes mentioned. I started my talk with something like "This talk is the background for the one [name of collaborator] just gave." It got some laughs, and no disaster ensued.